# mysql optimisation number of ads in a category

Tags: php, mysql

I have a personal ads website .

First problem: I have 2 tables, `category` and `ads`.

`Category` table (`id` is the primary key)

```
| id  | type        | subtype   | pos    |
+-----+-------------+-----------+--------+
| 1   | sell        |           | 1      |
| 2   | jobs        |           | 2      |
| 3   | dating      |           | 3      |
| 4   | dating      | boys      | 1      |
| 5   | dating      | girls     | 2      |
| 6   | sell        | cars      | 1      |
| 7   | jobs        | teacher   | 1      |
```

`Ads` table (`id` is the primary key) - this table has a lot of ads

```
| id  | title       | type      | subtype|
+-----+-------------+-----------+--------+
| 1   | some text   | sell      | cars   |
| 2   | some text   | dating    | girls  |
| 3   | some text   | dating    | boys   |
```

I want to read all category types and get the total number of ads for that type, and I need to get the subtypes too.

The output on my page will be something

```
Sell (1 ads)
   Cars

Jobs (0 ads)
   Teacher

Dating (2 ads)
  Boys
  Girls
```

What I am currently doing is making 3 queries using php and mysql, the first of which returns the categories type is a select where subtype="" , the second counts existing ads in those categories and the third gives me subtype for each type, I want to optimize mysql, reduce the number of queries and be faster even if it means changing the tables and adding more indexes

Select query:

```
select * 
from category  
where subtype = '' 
order by pos desc
```

Count numbers of ads on a type:

```
select type 
from ads 
where type = '$type_name'
```

Select subtype:

```
select * 
from category  
where type = '$type_name' 
  and subtype !='' 
order by pos
```

Comment: Please show us your existing queries.

Comment: Use `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
SELECT c.*,a.c_ads
FROM
category c LEFT JOIN ( SELECT COUNt(type) c_ads,type FROM ads GROUP BY type) a
ON c.type = a.type
ORDER BY c.type,c.pos DESC
```

> ```
> id | type   | subtype | pos | c_ads
> -: | :----- | :------ | --: | ----:
>  3 | dating |         |   3 |     2
>  5 | dating | girls   |   2 |     2
>  4 | dating | boys    |   1 |     2
>  2 | jobs   |         |   2 |  null
>  5 | jobs   | teacher |   1 |  null
>  1 | sell   |         |   1 |     1
>  5 | sell   | cars    |   1 |     1
> ```

[see fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7e0d094de7629b334427813e213e4ed4)

When you get the data in php check row by row, if the type changes and then you can can use the column c_ads to Display ($row{'c_ads'] ads) and row['type'] to display the text of the category

Where row['type'] doesn't change you find the subcategories to row['type'] in row['subtype ']

Comment: its working but is this counting the number of ads in every subtype ? if yes its not very efecient because I just need to count once every new type

Comment: No it is showing the number of ads for every type a you can see in the example dating has c_ads 2 because bys has 1 and girls has also 1 . the number for c_ads repeat it self for every subtype,.because ON c.type = a.type  The table above is only an internal one, you and of course me, are the only once who will see it. Your work is now to put this in php code and disaply teh data as you need. What you can do i did descrbe in the answer. Play with the Select in the fiddle add data and see what it does. and then build your html page